# Child routing with React v4?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Main route composition:

```
export const Routing = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={**Layout**}/>
        <Route path='/stats' component={Statistic}/>
        <Route path='/resource' component={Resource}/>
        <Route component={Notfound} />
    </Switch>
)
```

**Layout** (home page) component where I want to route to a child component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Navbar/>

            <Link to="/childComponent">Child</Link>

            <Route path="/childComponent" component={ChildComponent}/>

            <Navfooter/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I end up on page not found because of the non existing route. Why is that so? Doesn't my **Route path** do the route registration and I should easily be able to navigate via the **Link** tag...?

Comment: Why don't you put `<Route path="/childComponent" component={ChildComponent}/>` inside `Switch`? this way it would work.

Comment: @Tomasz Because I will loose my navbar component... As well as my other surrounding components

Comment: You shouldnt use a switch statement and a static route, instead use router and ${match.url}/youchildcomponent

Comment: Why shouldnt i use a switch for my parent routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to explain why you end up on `NotFound`. That's because when you click the link `path` changes to `/childComponent`. Props change and `Routing` component rerender with new props. Now `Switch` has to match new path `/childComponent`. He doesn't get any match and renders default component `NotFound`.

There are two ways you can go about this:

Changing the routing paths:

```
export const Routing = () => (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/layout' component={Layout}/>
        <Route path='/stats' component={Statistic}/>
        <Route path='/resource' component={Resource}/>
        <Route component={Notfound} />
      </Switch>
)


render() {
 return (
   <div className="container">
     <Navbar/>

     <Link to="/layout/childComponent">Child</Link>
     <Route path="/layout/childComponent" component={ChildComponent}/>

     <Navfooter/>
   </div>)
}
```

Another way is to reuse components:

```
export const Routing = () => (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Layout}/>
        <Route path="/childComponent" component={ChildComponent}/>
        <Route path='/stats' component={Statistic}/>
        <Route path='/resource' component={Resource}/>
        <Route component={Notfound} />
      </Switch>
)


const AppContainer = ({ children }) => (
   <div className="container">
     <Navbar/>
     {children}
     <Navfooter/>
   </div>
)

/** Layout **/
render() {
  return (
    <AppContainer>
      <Link to="/childComponent">Child</Link>
    </AppContainer>
   )
}

const ChildComponent = () => (
   <AppContainer/>
      ....
   <AppContainer/>
)
```

Comment: Yeap, that make sense... I' ll try and remove the not found and see how it goes

Comment: It won't render anything.